# Outputting returning a struct from a function

Tags: c, function, struct

so I'm trying to output a struct from a function in C. The code so far is:

```
//Step 1: Create a volume function that outputs a volume structure
//Step 2: Input boat dimensions from main
//Step 3: Use outputted volume values to calculate centre of gravity/buoyancy
//Step 4: Use values 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//Struct to fill with the values calculated in the submerged_volume function
struct vol {
    double V, Uc, Vc;
    };

struct vol submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H) {

    double C, delta, a, b, d;
    double theta, theta_rad, theta_min, theta_lim, theta_lim2, theta_lim_deg;
    double Ug1, Ug2, Vg1, Vg2, V1, V2;
    double pi; 

    pi = 4*atan(1);
    C = sqrt(L1*L1 + L2*L2);
    delta = acos(L1/C);

    theta_lim = asin(H/L1);
    theta_lim_deg = (theta_lim/pi) * 180.0;
    theta_min = asin(H/C) - delta; 
    theta_lim2 = 0;

    //Calling the structure to fill with values
    struct vol volume;


    double V_sub, Uc_sub, Vc_sub;
    V_sub = 0;

    //Volume calculations

    for (theta == 0; theta <= 10; theta = theta + 0.5) {
        theta_rad = (theta * pi)/180.0;
        //if (H > L2) { 
        printf(" H > L2\n");                          //Case where H > L2
            if (theta_rad > theta_lim) {
                V_sub = Lavg * L2 * (L2/(2.0 * tan(theta_rad)) + L1 - H/sin(theta_rad));
                //Case of triangle plus rectangle
                V1 = Lavg * L2 * L2/(2.0 * tan(theta_rad));     
                V2 = Lavg * L2 * (L1 - H/sin(theta_rad));
                Ug1 = -(H/sin(theta_rad) - L2/tan(theta_rad) + L2 * (cos(theta_rad)/(3.0*sin(theta_rad/2.0))));
                Vg1 = -(L2 - sin(theta_rad/2.0) * (L2/(3.0 * sin(theta_rad/2.0))));
                Ug2 = -(L1 + H/sin(theta_rad))/2.0;
                Vg2 = -L2/2.0;           //b 
                }
            else if (theta_rad > theta_min) {
                V_sub = Lavg * tan(theta_rad)/2.0 * pow((L1 - L2 * tan(theta_rad) - ((H - L2/cos(theta_rad))/sin(theta_rad))), 2);
                //Case of a triangle only 
                V1 = V_sub;
                V2 = 0; 
                Ug1 = -1.0/3.0 * (2.0 * L1 + L2 * tan(theta_rad) + (H - L2/cos(theta_rad))/sin(theta_rad));
                Vg1 = -(L2 - tan(theta_rad)/3.0 * (L1 - (H - L2/cos(theta_rad))/sin(theta_rad) - L2 * tan(theta_rad)));
                }
            else {
                V_sub = 0; 
                }
            //}

            if (V_sub != 0) {
            Uc_sub = Ug2 - V1/(V1 + V2) * (Ug2 - Ug1);
            Vc_sub = Vg2 - V1/(V1 + V2) * (Vg2 - Vg1);
            //moment = m * g * (b*sin(theta_rad) - a*cos(theta_rad)) + (Uc * cos(theta_rad) - Vc * sin(theta_rad)) * Fa - d * Fm;
            //fN = -(f * Fm * cos(theta_rad));
            //friction = m * g - Fa - Fm * sin(theta_rad);
            }
        }
    volume.V = V_sub;
    volume.Uc = Uc_sub;
    volume.Vc = Vc_sub;



    /*
    volume.V = 110;
    volume.Uc = 10;
    volume.Vc = 10;
    */

    return volume;
    }

int main() {

    double L1, L2, Lavg, H;
    struct vol volume; 

    printf("Enter L1: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &L1);
    printf("Enter L2: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &L2);
    printf("Enter Lavg: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &Lavg);
    printf("Enter H: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &H); 

    volume = submerged_volume(L1, L2, Lavg, H);

    printf("V = %lf\nUc = %lf\nVc = %lf\n", volume.V, volume.Uc, volume.Vc);

    return 0;
    }
```

I first tried it using just one set value for theta (theta == 5), which worked perfectly. I don't know if I can do this but I basically want to put a value for V, Uc, and Vc for each value of theta as it goes through the for loop. Is this possible? I hope this is explained ok, let me know if more details are needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a commentary, in C you normally just pass a pointer to the struct you want to "return" this is to avoid the memory copies required to pass return values on the stack (since structs are typically bigger than basic types).

Comment: Your expectation is that the result will be an array of `struct vol`, each containing the results for a given value of `theta`?  How should they map/index into one another?  Is it sufficient if for `theta == 0`, `volume_array[0]` contains the resulting `struct vol`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean? I'm pretty new at C so all of this is very new to me... Can you explain, please?

Comment: Just return the `struct`. As pointed by @Joseph, "The compiler will likely eliminate unnecessary copying anyway".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper way to achieve this is by passing output struct to the function either by reference or via a pointer:

```
// Declare
void submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H, struct vol& out);

// Use
struct vol volume;
submerged_volume(L1, L2, Lavg, H, volume);
```

Or via a pointer:

```
// Declare
void submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H, struct vol *out);

// Use
struct vol volume;
submerged_volume(L1, L2, Lavg, H, &volume);
```

Comment: Call the function using a reference to a structure OR have the function return a pointer to a (different) structure.

Answer (score 0):

**Point #1:** Your code has at least one bug, which may be the cause of your problem. A quick compilation gave me the following warnings:

```
 In function 'submerged_volume':
40: warning: statement with no effect
40: warning: 'theta' is used uninitialized in this function
35: warning: 'Vc_sub' may be used uninitialized in this function
35: warning: 'Uc_sub' may be used uninitialized in this function
19: warning: 'Vg2' may be used uninitialized in this function
19: warning: 'Ug2' may be used uninitialized in this function
```

In particular, on line 40:

```
for (theta == 0; theta <= 10; theta = theta + 0.5) {
           ^^
           want "=" here
```

**Point #2:** By the way, you should ignore the suggestions about `submerged_volume` using pointers rather than returning a `struct`, for two reasons.

- The structure here is so small that it makes no difference.
- The compiler will likely eliminate unnecessary copying anyway (e.g. by implicitly using a pointer).

**Point #3:** The OP clarified that he/she wished to return an *array* of structures. In this case we *do* need to add pointers, since arrays are not 'first class objects" in C. Something like:

In `main()`:

```
 struct vol volume[21];
 // ...
 submerged_volume(L1, L2, Lavg, H, volume);
 // ...
```

In `submerged_volume()`:

```
 void submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H, struct vol out[])
 // ...
 int i = theta * 2;
 // ...
 out[i].V  = V_sub;  // at bottom of loop
 out[i].Uc = Uc_sub;
 out[i].Vc = Vc_sub;
```

Or use the perhaps more common idiom:

```
 void submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H, struct vol *out)
 // ...
 out->V  = V_sub;  // at bottom of loop
 out->Uc = Uc_sub;
 out->Vc = Vc_sub;
 out++;
```

(Note my use here of the hard-coded `21` is a bad idea.)

Comment: ***Edit***: By the way, you should ignore the suggestions about using pointers rather than returning a `struct`, for two reasons. 1) The structure here is so small that it makes no difference. 2) The compiler will likely eliminate unnecessary copying anyway.

Comment: Hi sorry I've been away and just saw this now... I don't really understand what you mean. Basically, I'm trying to return an array of structures.